# Add grand total and subtotal for Pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index, subtotal

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Region':['Oceanian','Europe','Asia','America','Europe','America','Asia','Oceanian','America'],'Country':["AU","GB","KR","US","GB","US","KR","AU","US"],'Region Manager':['TL','JS','HN','AL','JS','AL','HN','TL','AL'],'Campaign Stage':['Start','Develop','Develop','Launch','Launch','Start','Start','Launch','Develop'],'Product':['abc','bcd','efg','lkj','fsd','opi','vcx','gtp','qwe'],'Curr_Sales': [453,562,236,636,893,542,125,561,371],'Curr_Revenue':[4530,7668,5975,3568,2349,6776,3046,1111,4852],'Prior_Sales': [235,789,132,220,569,521,131,777,898],'Prior_Revenue':[1530,2668,3975,5668,6349,7776,8046,2111,9852]})
table=pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Curr_Sales', 'Curr_Revenue', 'Prior_Sales', 'Prior_Revenue'], index=['Region','Country', 'Region Manager','Campaign Stage','Product'],aggfunc='sum')
```

[image]

How can I add subtotals to each "Region" and a Grand total at the bottom?

Any thoughts are appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I think this is almost same as you previous question

Comment: This code is not working. It combines all rows together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly similar solution to your previous question, however you can insert blank strings for your missing levels (inspired by @piRSquared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53121448/8146556)):

```
out = pd.concat([d.append(d.sum().rename((k, '', '', '', 'Subtotal'))) for k, d in table.groupby('Region')]).append(table.sum().rename(('Grand', '', '', '', 'Total')))

out.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(out.index)
```

Yields:

```
                                 Curr_Revenue     ...       Prior_Sales
America  US AL Develop qwe               4852     ...               898
               Launch  lkj               3568     ...               220
               Start   opi               6776     ...               521
                       Subtotal         15196     ...              1639
Asia     KR HN Develop efg               5975     ...               132
               Start   vcx               3046     ...               131
                       Subtotal          9021     ...               263
Europe   GB JS Develop bcd               7668     ...               789
               Launch  fsd               2349     ...               569
                       Subtotal         10017     ...              1358
Oceanian AU TL Launch  gtp               1111     ...               777
               Start   abc               4530     ...               235
                       Subtotal          5641     ...              1012
Grand                  Total            39875     ...              4272
```

Comment: Actually, @piRSquared's answer works for three indexes. But this df has five indexes, which is not working.

Comment: What is not working with the above? "Not working" provides no clarity to your issue.

Comment: @Boomshakalaka 3 and 5 or even 100 , the logic here is all the same

Comment: Hi @rahlf23, the new code answers my question and I appreciate your help. Thank you